# Resetting windows idle time

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes

I have written a small program, that keeps my computers awake even, when the battery settings can not be changed: https://github.com/xlaech/Anti-Lock-5000. My current setup uses clicks to reset the idle timer.

I was asking myself: Since there is a struct that saves the idle time (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-lastinputinfo) is there a way to override this value, keeping the computer from going to sleep without any action visible to the user?

While a solution in python is not necessary - it needs to be a portable solution (e.g. no libraries, no downloads).

Comment: [`SetThreadExecutionState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`SetThreadExecutionState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate) (as mentioned by [@IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable)):

```
import time
from ctypes import windll

ES_CONTINUOUS = 0x80000000          # Causes the set state to remain
ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = 0x00000002    # Forces the display to be on

flags = ES_CONTINUOUS | ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED

windll.kernel32.SetThreadExecutionState(flags)
while True:
    time.sleep(36000)    # Keep process alive, but sleep to prevent system load
```